# Scala: Write Random Values to JSON and Save in File then Analyze in Spark

Tags: json, scala, file, random

I would like to write ten (or a billion) events to JSON and save as files.

I am writing in a Databricks notebook in Scala.  I want the JSON string to have randomly generated values for fields like "Carbs":

```
{"Username": "patient1", "Carbs": 92, "Bolus": 24, "Basal": 1.33, "Date": 2017-06-28, "Timestamp": 2017-06-28 21:59:...}
```

I successfully used the following to write the date to an Array() and then save as a JSON file.

```
val dateDF = spark.range(10)
  .withColumn("today", current_date())
```

But what is the best way to write random values to an Array and then save the Array as a JSON file?

Comment: do you already have a dataframe and want to add a new column as random value ?

Comment: Yes.  Or, better yet, just create the dataframe with all of the columns in the first place.  Then use something like to_json() to write the DF to a file.  Similar to: https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/complex-nested-structured.html

Comment: rather than generating a random data you can use data set from different sites like kaggle

Comment: Yes.  But that means I'm restricted to their data.  I would strongly prefer to create my own data sets -- we then use these in a streaming platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert RDD to dataframe and then save as json format as

```
dataframe.write.mode('append').json(path)
```

Comment: Thanks Shankar!  My objective now is to create dataframes with random values in fields.  The following does this for the time function. val dateDF = spark.range(10).withColumn("today", current_date()).  Now I want to substitute "current_date()" for other functions that create various values.

Comment: here is a function to get random value https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#rand()

Comment: to get random string create a udf that returns random string, use   Random.alphanumeric.take(10).mkString to get random string of size 10